# InfluxDB FluxQL query to show daily average over longer period

Tags: influxdb

I'm trying to get a Flux query that shows me what an average day looks like, over a given period. More specifically, I'm querying power usage data of my freezer, gathered and sent to InfluxDB by home assistant.
As a very basic example, if my freezer would have used 100W during the first 15 days of a 30 day period, and 0W during the last 15 days, the daily average of that 30 day period would be 50W.
What I want to see is a graph of a 24h time period, but with the average data of month.

I have this basic query which shows me a months worth of data:

```
from(bucket: "home_assistant/autogen")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["friendly_name"] == "Shelly plug S Freezer Power 0")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1h, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "mean")
```

By playing with the `aggregateWindow` function, changing the `every` parameter to `1d` will show me the average data per day over those 30 days, but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have  30 days average you can take a look at the [timeMovingAverage](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/query-data/flux/moving-average/). It will return an average of the current value and all row values in the **previous** period (duration). It returns moving averages at a frequency defined by every parameter.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I don't think this is what I'm looking for, since `movingAverage` and `timedMovingAverage` take n number of rows (either a fixed number, or based on time intervals) and calculate the average of all those rows. Although it's close to what I'm looking for. If I have 30 days of data, I would like to see average values of all rows timestamped 'around' the same hour. So e.g. the average of 30 days at 00:00h, average of 30 days at 01:00h, etc...